# How may one show that $\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{n-1}e^{-x^n}\ln^2(x)\mathrm dx={6\gamma^2+\pi^2\over 6n^3}?$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, euler-mascheroni-constant

Observing

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}\ln^2(x)\mathrm dx=\gamma^2+{\pi^2\over 6}\tag1$$

The general of $(1)$ would be

> $$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{n-1}e^{-x^n}\ln^2(x)\mathrm dx={6\gamma^2+\pi^2\over 6n^3}\color{red}?\tag2$$

Where $n\ge 1$

**My try:**

Too complicate, I don't where to begin.

**How may one prove $(2)?$**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the change of variable
$$
u=x^n,\qquad du=n\cdot x^{n-1}dx,
$$ one gets
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{n-1}e^{-x^n}\ln^2(x)\:\mathrm dx=\frac1{n^2}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{n-1}e^{-x^n}\ln^2(x^{n})\:\mathrm dx=\frac1{n^3}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-u}\ln^2(u)\:\mathrm du
\end{align}
$$then you can finish with your result $(1)$.

Comment: thank you, you are too quick!, I thought it was sort of interesting result, but it seems not.

Comment: @AbuHurayrah France has great mathematicians :P

Comment: yes you are absolutely right, he is one of my favourite mathematician.

Comment: Abu Hurayrah: Next time, please, repack better the integral you want to modify. I know you can do better than that ;)